# Cartoon short film involving mission to a Mars base which fired missiles to Earth containing creatures

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, short-film

I am trying to identify an animated (short) film that I watched when I was a kid, I am estimating around 1995-1998 but could be way off. It would have been on VHS at the time.

I remember:

- Humans having to fly to a base on Mars for an identified threat, but it was a trick by the bad guys to allow pods/missiles to be launched to Earth containing creatures/robots
- A giant crab landed in the ocean, they fought at a lighthouse/beach.
- A giant praying mantis - I think it fired (red) lasers from its eyes. It got cut in half eventually in an aerial fight with planes/space ships.

I think it was quite realistically drawn, possibly with a slight Japanese anime feel to it. Human characters were adults. I think it was in English.

Answer (score 4):

*[Gaiking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaiking%3A_Legend_of_Daiku-Maryu)* is what it was called in the USA.  Came out in the late 60's.  Part of Jim Terry's Force Five.

> Five years ago, Daiya Tsuwabuki was on a fishing trip with his father when giant monsters attacked. Daiya was saved by the crew of Daiku Maryu. In the present, Daiya believes that his father is still alive, but no one believes him, not even his own mother. However, when the same monsters attack the city, Daiya becomes the pilot of Gaiking and joins Daiku Maryu as they go to the world of Darius to stop them from taking over the Earth.